# Dojo Tree Search Filters

Tags: tree, dojo

In one of my projects i have used Dojo tree plugin using ItemFileWriteStore & ForestStoreModel.

I have achieved DND, Contextmenu & Tool tip on the Tree view. But I can't figure out how to search a node or child node in the Tree.

I am looking for similar kind of implementation (http://jsfiddle.net/slemmon/fSJwF/2/), but seems to be this is implemented in some other library.

Could anybody please help me how to implement the same in DOJO.

Below is my code:

```
var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
        data:  data
  });

var treeModel = new dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel({
        rootId: "id",
        rootLabel: "label",
        store: store,
        breadCrumb : 'bcInfo',
        childrenAttrs: ["children"]
    });

     var treeControl = new dijit.Tree({
        model: treeModel,
        dndController: "dijit.tree.dndSource",
        persist: false,
        showRoot: false,
        onMouseOut: function(e){ 
            var node = dijit.getEnclosingWidget(e.target);
            dijit.Tooltip.hide(node.labelNode); 
        },
        onMouseOver: function(e) {          
            var node = dijit.getEnclosingWidget(e.target);
            if(node.item != undefined)
            {
                if(node.item.ToolTipContent != undefined)
                 dijit.Tooltip.show(node.item.ToolTipContent, node.labelNode);  
            }                           
        }
    }, "tree-view");
```

Comment: I think you can query the `treeModel` with the search options you want. From there you will probably be able to access the nodes

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I tried with query, i can able to filter root level  nodes. but I can't able to filter child nodes under root nodes.